# SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08S01 Communications link failure

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jdbc

I am getting this error (not so frequently):

```
2013-05-08 16:44:35,786  WARN (JDBCExceptionReporter.java:100) [org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter, logExceptions] - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08S01
2013-05-08 16:44:35,786 ERROR (JDBCExceptionReporter.java:101) [org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter, logExceptions] - Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
2013-05-08 16:44:35,833 ERROR (AdminDaoImpl.java:297) [com.myapp.admin.db.AdminDaoImpl, createFilePackage] - data-upload: Exception while adding new file package
org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Cannot open connection
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:97) [hibernate-core-3.3.2.GA.jar:3.3.2.GA]
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66) [hibernate-core-3.3.2.GA.jar:3.3.2.GA]
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:52) [hibernate-core-3.3.2.GA.jar:3.3.2.GA]
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:449) [hibernate-core-3.3.2.GA.jar:3.3.2.GA]
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:167) [hibernate-core-3.3.2.GA.jar:3.3.2.GA]
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.JDBCContext.connection(JDBCContext.java:142) [hibernate-core-3.3.2.GA.jar:3.3.2.GA]
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.begin(JDBCTransaction.java:85) [hibernate-core-3.3.2.GA.jar:3.3.2.GA]
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1354) [hibernate-core-3.3.2.GA.jar:3.3.2.GA]
    at com.myapp.admin.db.AdminDaoImpl. createFilePackage(AdminDaoImpl.java:182) [AdminDaoImpl.class:na]
    at com.myapp.admin.ctrl.UploadController.processUploadZip(UploadController.java:217) [UploadController.class:na]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor106.invoke(Unknown Source) [na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) [na:1.6.0_35]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) [na:1.6.0_35]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:212) [spring-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126) [spring-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96) [spring-webmvc-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617) [spring-webmvc-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578) [spring-webmvc-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80) [spring-webmvc-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:900) [spring-webmvc-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:827) [spring-webmvc-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882) [spring-webmvc-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789) [spring-webmvc-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647) [servlet-api.jar:na]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728) [servlet-api.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305) [catalina.jar:7.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) [catalina.jar:7.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222) [catalina.jar:7.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123) [catalina.jar:7.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472) [catalina.jar:7.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171) [catalina.jar:7.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99) [catalina.jar:7.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118) [catalina.jar:7.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407) [catalina.jar:7.0.35]
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.process(AjpProcessor.java:200) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.35]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.35]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.35]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [na:1.6.0_35]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [na:1.6.0_35]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [na:1.6.0_35]
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
```

I have two web (spring mvc + hibernate + mysql) applications hosted on shared server:

1) main app to show files for download (which is inserted through admin app)

2) admin app with CRUD operations

This error appears sometime, when I am using "admin" application to upload files for "main" app, lets say may be after successfully uploading/processing around 100-120 files/requests and on each request hitting database with 10-20 insert/update queries.

Hosting Details:

```
Private tomcat hosting
java 1.6.0_35-b10
tomcat 7.0.35
heap size 288MB
MySQL Server 5
commons-dbcp 1.2.2
mysql-connector-java 5.1.9
```

Database + Hibernate + DBCP properties:

```
<bean id="dbDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="username" value="test" />
    <property name="password" value="test" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/my_database?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8" />

    <!-- DBCP Connection Pool Settings -->
    <property name="defaultAutoCommit" value="true" />
    <property name="initialSize" value="10" />
    <property name="maxActive" value="500" />
    <property name="maxIdle" value="8" />
    <property name="minIdle" value="0" />
    <property name="maxWait" value="30000" />
    <property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1" />
    <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true" />
    <property name="testOnReturn" value="false" />
    <property name="testWhileIdle" value="false" />
    <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="-1" />
    <property name="numTestsPerEvictionRun" value="3" />
    <property name="minEvictableIdleTimeMillis" value="180000" />
    <property name="poolPreparedStatements" value="true" />
    <property name="maxOpenPreparedStatements" value="25" />
    <property name="accessToUnderlyingConnectionAllowed" value="false" />
    <property name="removeAbandoned" value="false" />
    <property name="removeAbandonedTimeout" value="300" />
    <property name="logAbandoned" value="false" />
</bean>

hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=none
hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=100
hibernate.show_sql=false
hibernate.format_sql=false
hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache=true
hibernate.cache.use_query_cache=false
hibernate.cache.provider_class=org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider
hibernate.current_session_context_class=thread
```

Concerned Code:

```
public String createFilePackage(FilePackage package) {
    String message = "";

    Session session = getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction tx = null;
    try {
        tx = session.beginTransaction();

        // handling package, around 10-14 DB insert, 10 SELECT and 5 update queries on same session

        tx.commit();

    } catch(Exception e) {
        logger.error("file-upload: Exception while adding new font package", e);
        if(tx != null) { tx.rollback(); }
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
    return message;
}
```

any advise how to solve this issue?

Comment: Look at the mysql logs.  See if there's something in them to explain why connections are being dropped unexpectedly.

Comment: It may be a transaction timeout?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The communication link between the driver and the data source to which the driver was attempting to connect failed before the function completed processing.
So usually its a network error. This could be caused by packet drops or badly configured Firewall/Switch.

Comment: I had a similar issue as described in the question. I concur with Marciej's answer. On an enterprise network, my local dev machine was dropping connections to the db server, however a deploy environment server which was behind a different set of firewalls was able to connect to the same db and maintain its connection without issues. My local dev machine would drop connection within 2 minutes of being setup. I also found that running off our wireless network maintained the connection, where wired did not (and both run through different routes/firewalls).

Comment: It can also happen with long running queries , when socket timeout is less than the query time.

jdbc:mariadb:aurora://myHost/db?socketTimeout=0
can be used to set the socketTimeout value.

Answer (score 9):

Check your server config file `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` - verify `bind_address` is not set to `127.0.0.1`. Set it to `0.0.0.0` or comment it out then restart server with:

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

Comment: I cant find `/etc/mysql` folder in my Mac. Do I need to search for any other file for Mac?

Comment: Thank you, this was my issue.

Comment: I have the same error but I didn't find bind_address in the config file. it may be the cause of the error ?

Answer (score 2):

I'm answering on specific to this error code(08s01).

usually, MySql close socket connections are some interval of time that is wait_timeout defined on MySQL server-side which by default is 8hours. so if a connection will timeout after this time and the socket will throw an exception which SQLState is "08s01".

1.use connection pool to execute Query, make sure the pool class has a function to make an inspection of the connection members before it goes time_out.

2.give a value of <wait_timeout> greater than the default, but the largest value is 24 days

3.use another parameter  in your connection URL, but this method is not recommended, and maybe deprecated.

Comment: this seems useful....can you explain more on these steps....how could i provide an inspection function and how wait_timeout works.

Answer (score 0):

Could be due to the TCP protocol turned off.

How to check/enable:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11377/cannot-connect-to-ms-sql-2008-r2-by-dbvisualizer-native-sspi-library-not-loade/144097#144097