# MySQL service shuts down while processing script

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table with ~150M rows and 3 columns. Currently testing DataGrip. I want to separate a string on the first column into two new columns, for instance:

`Test/out` should be separated into `Test` and `Out`

I'm currently using the following queries:

```
ALTER TABLE dataset ADD COLUMN id TEXT;
UPDATE dataset SET id = SUBSTR(id_type, 1, INSTR(id_type, '/') - 1);

ALTER TABLE dataset ADD COLUMN type TEXT;
UPDATE dataaset SET type = SUBSTR(id_type, INSTR(id_type, '/') + 1, LENGTH(id_type));
```

While using a limit, the script works. However, when I try to proccess the whole set, I get the following error, after some minutes:

```
[08S01] Communications link failure
The last packet successfully received from the server was 551,753 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 551,753 milliseconds ago.
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
```

The Windows Service (MySQL80) stops, and I need to restart it manually.

Already tried to:

- Update the J/Connector to the latest version
- Change some timeouts (connect_timeout, wait_timeout, interactive_timeout)
- Cheking my.conf and changing bind address

When I tried to run that script on a SQLite copy of the db, the process went ok. 
Tried to follow a lot of similar threads, but none of those worked.

Comment: Maybe a duplicate question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16459990/sql-error-0-sqlstate-08s01-communications-link-failure

Comment: Hi. I already tried those solutions, unfortunately without success. Since that question didn't refer the Windows Service crash, nor the dataset size, I asked a new one.

Comment: I don't have a response but for me it's a memory or buffer size problem  somewhere.

Comment: Can you see the error log ?

Comment: I'm not a heavy user of DataGrip, but the only logs I can see are the event and database logs. They both return simple errors like `10:37 Connected | 11:08 Connection to database_name failed. [08001] Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.` The event only says that the table edit (first query) was successful.

Comment: When trying directly from the terminal: `ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server during query`