# Communication link failure when inserting to MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm trying to insert CSV data into the MySQL table. But after adding 64 rows I get following error. I'm confused because 64 rows have added to the DB and it fails every time I try.

```
sql error, state:08S01
 message:Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
```

I'm using MySQL JDBC client in java and my MySQL parameters I have given like below.

```java
private String dbUrl = "jdbc:mysql://0.0.0.0:3306/amasyn_db";
private String dbUser = "root";
private String dbPassword = "root1234";
```

There was some hacks given but none of these worked in MacOS.

Comment: Details about the context are missing (mySQL configuration and the Java code).
This also seems to be duplicating question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16459990/sql-error-0-sqlstate-08s01-communications-link-failure

Comment: Details about debugging `Communication Link failure` exception may be found here: http://mysqlblog.fivefarmers.com/2010/09/06/debugging-communication-link-failure-exceptions-in-connectorj/

Comment: @AlexRudenko I cant find `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` file in my mac

Comment: Sorry, I've never been using Mac at all :)
Some answer can be [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10757169/location-of-my-cnf-file-on-macos)