# How can I fix this error? Crystal Reports

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

Greetings to the community.

I have the following errors when I try to link my stored procedure to crystal reports:

[image: imagen]

And also this:
[image: imagen2]

I hope you can understand the words in Spanish, if not let me know and I can post more pictures.

Comment: Please at least translate the error to English in Google translate for us, as you can copy and paste it. Thank you.

Comment: In public forums better write details in English.

Answer (score 0):

Error 08501 is a Communication Link Failure.

Here is another StackOverflow thread discussing possible reasons/solutions: [SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08S01 Communications link failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16459990/sql-error-0-sqlstate-08s01-communications-link-failure)