# Running SpringBoot and MySQL with Flyway in Docker

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, docker, flyway

Starting the spring boot application with a docker mysql instance ends up in the below exception. I have started the mysql docker instance and was able to view the databases via cli. I am not using docker-compose but docker commands as I am setting it up. I am following [this](https://www.javainuse.com/devOps/docker/docker-mysql) to run springboot/mysql in docker. However, only additional component which is not mentioned in the link is the usage of Flyway.

I started the mysql container in a network

```
docker run -it --name mysqldb --network=my-net -e MYSQL_ROOT_USER=sa -e 
 MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=1234 -e MYSQL_DATABASE=mydb -d mysql:latest
```

And then the springboot container in the same network which ends up in the below error

```
docker run --network=my-net --name manager-app -p 8080:8080 -d manager-app
```

Below is the container log of manager-app

```
        --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        SQL State  : 08S01
        Error Code : 0
        Message    : Communications link failure

        The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.

                at org.flywaydb.core.internal.jdbc.JdbcUtils.openConnection(JdbcUtils.java:60) ~[flyway-core-8.5.13.jar!/:na]
                at org.flywaydb.core.internal.jdbc.JdbcConnectionFactory.<init>(JdbcConnectionFactory.java:75) ~[flyway-core-8.5.13.jar!/:na]
                at org.flywaydb.core.FlywayExecutor.execute(FlywayExecutor.java:147) ~[flyway-core-8.5.13.jar!/:na]
                at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.migrate(Flyway.java:124) ~[flyway-core-8.5.13.jar!/:na]
                at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayMigrationInitializer.afterPropertiesSet(FlywayMigrationInitializer.java:66) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.7-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:2.7.7-SNAPSHOT]
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar!/:5.3.24]
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar!/:5.3.24]
                ... 26 common frames omitted
        Caused by: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

        The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
                at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar!/:8.0.31]
                at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar!/:8.0.31]
                at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:828) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar!/:8.0.31]
                at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:448) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar!/:8.0.31]
                at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:241) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar!/:8.0.31]
                at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:198) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar!/:8.0.31]
                at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
                at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:364) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
                at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
                at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:476) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
                at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
                at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
                at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
                at org.flywaydb.core.internal.jdbc.JdbcUtils.openConnection(JdbcUtils.java:48) ~[flyway-core-8.5.13.jar!/:na]
                ... 32 common frames omitted
        Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure

        The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
                at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
                at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
                at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:na]
                at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490) ~[na:na]
                at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar!/:8.0.31]
                at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar!/:8.0.31]
                at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:151) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar!/:8.0.31]
                at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:167) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar!/:8.0.31]
                at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:89) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar!/:8.0.31]
                at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:120) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar!/:8.0.31]
                at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:948) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar!/:8.0.31]
                at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:818) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar!/:8.0.31]
                ... 43 common frames omitted
        Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
                at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
                at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:399) ~[na:na]
                at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:242) ~[na:na]
                at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:224) ~[na:na]
                at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:na]
                at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609) ~[na:na]
                at com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:153) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar!/:8.0.31]
                at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:63) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar!/:8.0.31]
                ... 46 common frames omitted
```

I tried localhost and container name in the jdbc url but did not help. I am using the below configurations.

pom.xml

```
      <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.31</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
        <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
        <artifactId>flyway-mysql</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

application.yml

```
server:
  port: 8080

spring:
  application:
    name: manager-app
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://mysqldb:3306/mydb?useSSL=false
    driverClassName: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    username: root
    password: rootpass

  profiles:
    active: dev

  jpa:
    show-sql: true
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
        ddl-auto: update
  h2:
    console:
      enabled: true
  flyway:
    locations: classpath:db/migration
```

My target is to get the springboot service with Flyway and MySQL run in docker environment. Is there anything I am missing here? I am new to Flyway. Any help/hint is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: [Dup1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16459990/592355), [dup2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6865538/592355) ..in your case, i think you just forgot to forward/map the port of MySQL image ... `-p 3306:3306`

Comment: There is no `MYSQL_ROOT_USER` property for the container, hence the setting of the user to `sa` will not work and the user is still `root` and not `sa`.

Answer (score 1):

add `-p 3306:3306` to your docker run mysql command.
your command should be like this:

```
docker run -it --name mysqldb -p 3306:3306 --network=my-net -e MYSQL_ROOT_USER=sa -e 
 MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=1234 -e MYSQL_DATABASE=mydb -d mysql:latest
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql) of the MySQL Docker Container there is no `MYSQL_ROOT_USER` property. Hence trying to connect with user `sa` will fail as there is no user named `sa` but only `root`.

If you want to create a super-user use the `MYSQL_USER` and `MYSQL_PASSWORD`  properties.

```
docker run -it --name mysqldb --network=my-net -e 
 MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=1234 -e MYSQL_USER=sa -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=1234 -e MYSQL_DATABASE=mydb -d mysql:latest
```

This will change the password of the root user to `1234` and as well create a superuser named `sa` with the same password. Now the `sa` user should work (not sure what rights it has).

Or simply use the `root` user instead of `sa` in your application configuration.

```
spring:
  application:
    name: manager-app
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://mysqldb:3306/mydb?useSSL=false
    driverClassName: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    username: root
    password: 1234
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. However, when starting the service in docker-compose, I get the same error. The service container exits and mysql runs. Only when I restart the service container, it starts properly. I had applied `restart: always` for both service and mysql. What could be the reason here?

Comment: Your question states nothing about docker compose, where did that rabbit come from all of a sudden? It has also nothing to do with the initial question at hand which( according to your comment) seems resolved.

Comment: Absolutely, it's just the next step in the process. I wanted to somehow get it working so tried with docker-compose. Btw, I still face the connection issue while running the instance via docker commands

Comment: Then why you stated it starts properly? Did you actually modify either your user or added the other user?

Comment: Please see the docker-compose added to the question. I have not added a new user while using docker-compose if that's the question nor while running docker commands `docker run -it --name mysqldb --network mynet -p 3306:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=rootpass -e MYSQL_
DATABASE=mydb -d mysql:latest`

Comment: You edited my answer not thhe question!. Nonetheless if you still use `sa` for the user in your application properties it still won't connect as that is just the wrong user.

Comment: My bad, working on a tiny laptop.

Comment: Judging from that edit you still use `MYSQL_ROOT_USER` which doestn' exists, which means you haven't changed a bit only moved to docker compose and hoped it would work.

Comment: I have `username: root`  `password: rootpass`   `url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true` in the app.yml. The following are the commands used - `docker run -it --name mysqldb -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=rootpass -e MYSQL_DATABASE=mydb -d mysql:latest` & `docker run --name app -p 8080:8080 testapp`. Please let me know what I am missing here. The database gets created on app startup via flyway initialization.

Comment: Your config is confusing and inconsistent. I have no clue on what you have now or are trying. You are throwing a docker compose in there with different settings, now you claim you aren't using it. Your question now shows conflcting information. I give up. The error is in your configuration figure out what.